Trigonometric Fourier Series Half Period Shift and Negative Input Theorems
I am reading Howell (2016) Fourier Analysis, where 2 theorems are presented (9.9, 9.10)

Let $f$ be a periodic, piecewise continuous function with period $p$ and Fourier series
$$\mathcal{F}[f]|_{t} = A_{0} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Big[a_{k} \cos(2\pi \omega_{k}t) + b_{k}\sin(2\pi \omega_{k}t)\Big]$$
If $g(t)=f(-t)$, then $g$ is a periodic, piecewise continuous function with period $p$ and trigonometric Fourier series
$$\mathcal{F}[g]|_{t} = A_{0} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Big[a_{k} \cos(2\pi \omega_{k}t) - b_{k}\sin(2\pi \omega_{k}t)\Big] \tag{1}$$

and

[!theorem] Theorem Half Period Shift ([[../../../PDFs/howell2016.pdf#page=125|Source]])
Let $f$ be a periodic, piecewise continuous function with period $p$ and Fourier series
$$\mathcal{F}[f]|_{t} = A_{0} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Big[a_{k} \cos(2\pi \omega_{k}t) + b_{k}\sin(2\pi \omega_{k}t)\Big]$$
If $g(t) = f\left( t- \frac{p}{2} \right)$, then $g$ is periodic, piecewise continuous function with period $p$ and
$$\mathcal{F}[g]|_{t} = A_{0} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \Big[(-1)^k a_{k} \cos(2\pi \omega_{k}t) + (-1)^k b_{k}\sin(2\pi \omega_{k}t)\Big]\tag{2}$$

I want to prove both of them. So, if I understand the statements correctly, that given some periodic, piecewise continuous function $f$ which can be represented as Fourier series with coefficients  $A_0, a_k, b_k$. Then given $f(t) = g(-t)$ (for first theorem) the coefficients don't change, if we take the adapted formulas into account (1,2).
Now, if I want to prove these, for the first theorem the computations on sine and cosine are straight forward. But for $A_0$ for instance I am a little clueless on how to work this out. So, I understand I have to show the following for the first theorem
$$A_0 = \frac{1}{p} \int_{0}^p f(t) = \frac{1}{p} \int_{0}^p f(-t)$$
(also for $a_k, b_k$)
I am not sure if I misunderstand the theorems or if I just don't see the trick on to show these identities. Maybe a small bump in the right direction would be helpful enough for me.
